# node-tesseract-ocr how to use patterns

Tags: node.js, ocr, tesseract

I installed the "node-tesseract-ocr" library and I have this code:

```
const tesseract = require("node-tesseract-ocr")

const config = {
    lang: "ita",
    dpi: 400,
    oem: 1,
    psm: 3,
    "user-patterns": "public/patterns/patterns.txt"
}




tesseract
        .recognize("public/images/image_1.png", config)
        .then((text) => {
            res.status(201).json({
                data: text
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            res.status(401).json({
                error: error.message
            });
        })
```

in the patterns.txt file I have this:

```
\A\A\A\A\A\A\d\d\A\d\d\A\d\d\d\A
```

The image contains this type of fonts that interest me:

```
FFFFFF00F00F000F
```

The result is that it returns all the text correctly but does not apply the pattern and therefore does not return just what I am interested in.
I don't understand where I'm wrong, who can help me?

Comment: You have used `ita` language, have you placed it in the data path? Also attach a sample `png` file for further review (since you have used a specific language that I am not familiar with).